# Apply Chart Template to Excel Chart

Tags: c#, wpf, excel-interop

I've successfully managed to create a chart in Excel using WPF.  I can apply stock Excel layouts to the chart using:

```
xlChart.ApplyLayout(i);
```

Where xlChart is my chart and 'i' represents the layout I choose.

However, I want to go a step further than this and apply my own custom chart type.  I've created a chart type in Excel, and saved it as a crtx file.  I've added this to my project as an embedded resource, and attempted to apply it to the Excel chart as follows:

```
var file = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Templates/line.crtx");
xlChart.ApplyChartTemplate(file.AbsoluteUri);
```

However, this fails with

```
HRESULT_FAIL
```

I am probably not referencing the template properly, so hopefully someone out there will be able to assist!

Edit:

I have managed to find a workaround.  I can copy the template to the output directory and reference it using:

```
var path = Path.GetFullPath("Resources/Templates/line.crtx");
xlChart.ApplyChartTemplate(path);
```

However, I would prefer to have the chart as an embedded resource for the sake of tidiness.  I guess you can't have everything!

Comment: It looks like chart templates is another good feature not well integrated [Excel Blog - Chart Templates](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2008/02/21/chart-templates.aspx). Perhaps you could you serialize your resource to a tempfile and then apply it.